# Is it possible to customize the tool window's toolbars in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, customization

Visual Studio 2010 has UI for editing the buttons in the toolbars of the main window. Is it possible to do the same thing for the tool window toolbars?

[image: Sample toolbar]

Even if there is no UI, I am willing to alter files manually to get the expected result. Basically, the problem I am trying to solve is that some tool windows hide the buttons that I want to use and show buttons that I don't use. I would like to reorder them.

Comment: I found something on MSDN, it might be useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx

Comment: The link above explains how to edit menus and toolbars, but not the toolbars of the tool windows.

Comment: At my previous comment I wanted to say that I've never seen any ability like this before in VS but I saw that link and thought it would help. As you're saying, sometimes I wanted to modify floating windows like you said but I couldn't really. I don't know maybe there is a lack in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

No.

---

Hmm that answer was not long enough.

It is not possible.